# How to check if the value not in the table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, not-exists

I am creating a sql query that use where in, how to return false if the value not in the table.

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

My content has 1, 2 ,3,4, return 1 and 2, but if 3,4 are not in the table, how to return a message says 3,4 are not in the table.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: You should clarify which database this is. It's unlikely you want to do this in both SQLite and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `NOT` keyword:

`select * from table where id NOT in (1,2,3,4)`

Note that `NULL` values will never pass either an IN or a NOT IN.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. But I want to select 1,2 which they are in the table, but 3,4 are null, I want to have a result for 1,2 but have a message for 3, 4 that they are null.

Comment: Because not in query will return all the values in the table except 1,2

Comment: @grevisha In that case your original code is correct. You will not get any results from the database for 3 or 4. Your application code then sees that 3/4 don't have any results returned and it prints out your message. Generally speaking this isn't something you should be doing database side.